# What versions of rails is supported with puma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I have a very old rails 2.x application, will puma be able to run this application?

I can't seem to find a rails version compatibility chart for puma.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you upgrade and be on the safer side.

Actually, puma is default rails server, what you should consider upfront is bugs due to ruby version.
The answer is yes.

Comment: Please provide an actual answer - This is more comment-material.. May be any number of reasons not to upgrade.

Comment: What's your ruby version...?